# typescript How to get types in html script tag

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

How to import types in `script` tag in html file

package.json is like

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.167"
  }
}
```

index.html is like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-ur/YlHMU96MxHEsy3fHGszZHas7NzH4RQlD4tDVvFhw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script>
    // @ts-check
    const x = _.chuck([1,2,3]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

how to resolve this error
`Cannot find name '_'.`

[image]

Comment: _:any; assign type any;

Comment: Actually I want `_` to typed as lodash from `@types/lodash` , and you cann put type annotations in  script tag as it not a typescript file

Comment: @AbdulKareem Hi, do you have any update on this ? Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @BenjaminB not yet